Rollup effort from "Story points" fields to Parent field in ADO
I want to Rollup effort from "Story Points" field in all child User Stories to "Total Effort" field in Feature in ADO
For Example: If there are 2 user stories with 3 and 5 story points respectively, I would like to see the value 8 in the "Total Effort" field in the Feature.
I have tried plugin "Rollup Field" but, it is inconsistent in updating the value. So, it is not helping out.
I have tried setting up Rules in the User Story, but did not help
Please suggest any recommendations.

You can add a rollup column to your backlog to get the total of the story points.
Steps: Open the backlog, select the Column options, choose Add a rollup column, select From quick list, and then choose Sum of Story Points.
For example, I have 2 child user stories with 3 and 5 story points. The Total Story Points column shows that the total story points of the parent feature are 8.


Thank you for the feedback. This certainly helps.
In my case, I am also expected to flag the positive effort variance between Feature estimation and the consolidated Story Points Effort( Example 8).
Each Feature would be estimated with Story points in the beginning lets say 80 SPs.
As we add stories to the feature, with the above method you have suggested, we will know the cumulated value of Story Points(SP) across all user stories.
It might be difficult for users to understand the variance and only look at those features where positive variance is beyond 15%.

Hi @KrishnaPunekar, in the feature work item, there is no default field named "Total Effort". Do you mean that you have created a custom field named "Total Effort"? Currently, there is no out-of-box functionality to automatically roll up the effort from the "story points" field in all child user stories into the "total effort" field in the feature. You can request the feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better.

By the way, I'm not sure if you're interested in writing a script to use the REST API to update the work item fields.  Or using the PowerBI to get the report, for example: Rollup child work item values to parent sample report.

I shall check with Azure for the new feature.
Thank you all, will also check the REST API option and try to see if it helps.

Hi @KrishnaPunekar, thanks for your update. Please let me know if there is more that I can help you with the issue.
